# TLS1.3 version mismatch

Tags: ssl, wireshark

I want to capture a sample SSL traffic with wireshark, which it's version is TLS1.3(newest version). I enabled the  TLS 1.3(draft23) flag in chrome browser, and also update my wireshark to version 2.6.2.

then I start to open some sites like https://gmail.com and https://www.thesslstore.com which supports this version and capture the traffic.

but when I open the captured traffic, the version of SSL header is TLS1.0 or TLS1.3 while in the section of the protocol in the top of window, TLSv1.3 is showed.

Comment: This is not really a programming question (so offtopic here) and you are not exactly super clear, but depending on which part of the exchange you look at (what is *top of window*?), seeing TLS1.0 is not strange, even if the exchange is TLS1.3

Answer (score 1):

There are routers, gateways, etc. that look at this header.  Because TLS 1.3 is somewhat new, you will often see older TLS versions specified.  I most often see TLS 1.2, but my code talks to AWS - that may be their standard.